# Did anyone tried to use ClaimRow() for one-time send to a large number of target audiences?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder, email-studio

I have developed an AMPScript block that uses the ClaimRow() function and it is working very smoothly when we send emails via Journey Builder. But now, we aim to send an Ad-hoc email to a large number of target audiences (estimated 1 million) where we also need to use the ClaimRow() functionality. Has anyone tried this before? If yes, did you encounter any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using ClaimRowValue (not ClaimRow, but I would suppose that similar logics apply in terms of performance) for a customer that performs bulk sendouts with 1 - 2.5 mio recipients, with no known issues.